# Переход на HTTPS WordPress

Tags: wordpress, ssl

Хочу установить https на сайт. Во всех инструкциях сказано, что нужно поменять Адрес WP и сайта в общих настройках, однако мне WP не дает этого сделать. Прав достаточно, для уверенности даже нового юзера заводил. Что можно сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

> Во всех инструкциях сказано, что нужно поменять Адрес WP и сайта в
> общих настройках, однако мне WP не дает этого сделать.

Если ВП "не дает этого сделать" значит адреса могут быть прописаны в конфиге или в файле функций темы.

Но заменить в настройках - этого не достаточно. Менять протокол нужно с пом специальных плагином, делающих корректную замену в базе - с учётом сериализованных данных. Например при помощи https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/

Answer (score 0):

Я обычно использую плагин Really Simple SSL. После активации он проверяет действительно ли на хостинге к домену имеется сертификат, и если всё ок - в один клик делает все необходимые операции по переходу на https.

Comment: Это плохое решение. Уже потому, что подобные плагины  не заменяет ничего в базе, а все меняют на лету. И это только часть проблем.

Comment: В базе как раз есть нужные изменения благодаря плагину. А если речь идет про ссылки на материалы, то если руками их до этого не прописывать через http, то на относительных путях всё прекрасно работает. Не помню проблем с этим.

Comment: Нет, эти плагины  в базе протокол не меняют.  Все делается в реалтайме при выводе.

Comment: Не вижу смысла спорить. На всех моих сайтах плагин Really Simple SSL поменял в БД протокол.

Comment: Правильно - нечего спорить. Надо просто взять и посмотреть в базе ссылки с доменом.